# how to get names of worksheets in excel file?

Tags: javascript

i am new in JavaScript programming
i want java script to find the names of worksheets in excel file
scenario
1) file upload control in a HTML
2) when user selects the file 
3) HTML text box should display comma separated names of worksheet

||**_*|*_**||_*|****|*_**||_*|
|*|_|_*|****|*_**||_*|****|*_**|
||**_*|*_**||_*|****|*_**||__|
__GERMANY__/__UK__/__IRELAND__/

Please also suggest me event of file upload control on which call to java script function is to be made
thanks in advance

Comment: javascript cannot read excel file, at least not that i am aware of

Comment: @Ibu - javascript can read an Excel sheet but you have to use an ActiveX object and thus you have to use Internet Explorer.  It is ugly at best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't posted any code here, so I will assume you haven't even started this process and you need to know where to go.  Basically, what you want to do is possible but it will be a lot of work and it will only work on Internet Explorer (because you use ActiveX).

To start with, here is a forum post that gives some example code of opening an Excel file and working with it.  This will be a good place to start:

http://forums.devarticles.com/javascript-development-22/pulling-and-displaying-data-from-excel-spreadsheet-47084.html

Next, you will need to look at the Excel Object Model reference guide for any features or functionality you may want:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb149081.aspx

Specifically, you want to look at the Sheets list:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb178404(v=office.12).aspx

Basically, you should be able to open the Excel file and reference the Sheets() list to get the names of all of the sheets in the file.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old thread but it was the only one I found that worked and is simple. The answer above however is out of date. So here's a working ver. for JSZip 3.0

```
function getTab (base64file) {
    var result = [];
    var s, i, id;
    var zip = new JSZip();
    zip.loadAsync(base64file, {
        base64: true
    }).then(function(zip) {

        var t;
        if (t = zip.file('xl/workbook.xml')) {
            t.async("string").then(function (data) {
                s = data;
                s = s.split('<sheet ');
                i = s.length;
                while (--i) {
                    id = s[i].substr(s[i].indexOf('name="') + 6);
                    result.push(id.substring(0, id.indexOf('"')));
                }

            });
        }
    });
}
```

The code is almost the same but JSZip now uses async methods and expects you'll wait for it then do something. Hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

- Convert the Excel file into a [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) representation
- Load the above base64 string into [jszip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/)
- Parse the worksheet names from `x1/workbook.xml`

Example:

```js
'use strict'; // v2.3.2
var result, zip = new JSZip(),
  processStartTime, s, i, index, id;

var getTab = function(base64file) {

  zip = zip.load(base64file, {
    base64: true
  });
  result = [];
  processStartTime = Date.now();

  if (s = zip.file('xl/workbook.xml')) {
    s = s.asText();

    s = s.split('<sheet ');
    i = s.length;
    while (--i) { 
      id = s[i].substr(s[i].indexOf('name="') + 6);
      result.push(id.substring(0, id.indexOf('"')));
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('tab-names').innerText = result;
  console.log(Date.now(), processStartTime, result)
}

var handleFileSelect = function(evt) {
  var files = evt.target.files;
  var file = files[0];

  if (files && file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(readerEvt) {
      var binaryString = readerEvt.target.result;
      getTab(btoa(binaryString));
    };

    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
  }
};

if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
  document.getElementById('filePicker').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
} else {
  alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.6.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label for="filePicker">Choose or drag a file:</label>
  <br>
  <input type="file" id="filePicker">
</div>
<h3>Tab names</h3>
<pre id='tab-names'></pre>
```